# Membership imports

Tags: civimember, contacts, custom-fields, duplicate-contacts, data-import

Can I import membership contact and membership details all in one upload without my contact already existing?  Or does my contact need to already be a contact for me to upload membership specifics - and it takes two uploads not one.

Plus, I have a field called Membership Organisation which when importing my data gives a reason of ' invalid; membership type (which is a separate field).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the built-in CiviCRM import can't do contacts and memberships together.  You need to do two uploads.  Worse still, if they're paid memberships, you have to do three uploads - though folks have written extensions to address this (see other questions [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19526/simple-way-to-import-membership-and-contributions-together) and [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/1/whats-the-best-way-to-import-memberships-and-their-associated-contributions).  No one has made a general "works for everyone" extension though.

Comment: As for your second issue - Stack Exchange works best if there's a single question per post.  Could you please post that as a separate question, and include a sample line of (anonymized) data, including your headers?  I wonder if your CSV file is malformed.